# Jenkins throws an exception: build step 'invoke top-level maven targets' marked build as failure

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

Jenkins throws the following error:

```
[WARNING] The requested profile "singleflow" could not be activated because it does not exist.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project factor-esb-autotest: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 10 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
build step 'invoke top-level maven targets' marked build as failure
```

My POM https://pastebin.com/xeb5Mpcb

At first I thought that the error was due to the fact that in the jenkins global settings the version does not match the plugin (3.8.1), I set it to "Install from Apach" 3.8.1 but it still does not work. What could be the reason ?

Maven in global setting

[image]

Comment: The problem: `Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 10` this means you are using JDK8 or less to compile that project...

Comment: I'm using java 8. This error appeared after I updated my POM and JUNIT

Comment: Something you updated is specifying Java 10 as a target, so you must install Java 11 (since 10 deprecated) or find the offender and either back out or work around (unlikely). You'd have to post what you changed and the effective pom but should easy to figure out

Comment: so there must be a configuration for maven-compiler-plugin (`<release>10</release>`) or a property like `<maven.compiler.release>10</maven.compiler.release>`) .. JUnit has nothing to do with that...apart from that such information that you have update pom should be part of the question up-front.

Comment: @khmarbaise you solved my problem, you can post your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a configuration for maven-compiler-plugin (`<release>10</release>`) or a property like `<maven.compiler.release>10</maven.compiler.release>`

The commented upgrade of JUnit is unrelated to the problem.

Apart from that such information that you have update pom should be part of the question up-front